# Generating a 10 digit security token

Tags: c#, security

I'm look at algorithms and ways to generating a 10 digit security token. I've tried the following:

```
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        var buffer = new byte[4];
        rng.GetBytes(buffer);
        int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
        var token = Math.Abs(result).ToString();
```

The problem is RNGCryptoServiceProvider seems to return around 9 to 10 digits. I've consider add an extra random numbers if it contains less than 10 digits however I not convinced this is the best approach.

appreciate any advice or recommendations.

Comment: Does this token need to be unique throughout your system?

Comment: Only digits, as a developer wasn't my choice to be 10 digits.

Comment: Collisions become pretty likely once you get to 10^5 tokens. So just generating a random token and hoping it is unique doesn't work well here. I recommend checking if the generated token already exists, and if yes, generate a new one.

Comment: 1+ @CodeInChaos its a very valid point. I've already considered this and I'm maintaining the tokens in a table to reference the provided token for a given session and checking before generating. thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pad the result with zeros to get 10 digits. Also, you should rather use a `ulong` to get the full range of 10 digits.

```
var buffer = new byte[8]; // 8 bytes for a long
rng.GetBytes(buffer);
ulong result = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 0); // unsigned to avoid having to use Abs
var token = result.ToString("D10"); // pads the result to 10 digits
token = token.Substring(token.Length - 10); // strip out extra digits, if any
```

Comment: How is this guaranteed to be unique? Random, yes, but not unique.

Comment: @Darin: OP didn't specify that it must be unique when I wrote this. You could always keep generating tokens until you get an unused one though.

Comment: 1+ for the unsigned to avoid having to use Abs, I'm curious about D10, and how it strips the extra numbers. I'll need do some reading on that. thanks Matti Virkkunen

Comment: @Nickz: `D10` means "decimal, pad to 10 digits" which ensures that we get at least 10 digits (it adds leading zeros if the number had less than 10 digits - this is rarely necessary because most `ulongs` are way longer than that). The stripping part just takes the last 10 characters of the string (no need to do checks because `D10` guarantees there's at least 10)

Comment: thank you @Matti Virkkunen for the info and updated code example. I have my reservations about adding zeros however it is very likely RNGCryptoServiceProvider for byte of 8 will always return a greater than 10 digit ulong.

Comment: @Nickz: Yeah, the probability of getting less than 10 digits back is pretty small. What's wrong with adding zeros btw?

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen I'd prefer do something like char extraBitPadder = new Random().Next(10).ToString().ToCharArray()[0]; token =token.PadRight(maxTokenDigits, extraBitPadder);

Comment: @Nickz That's worse. This code returns all possible numbers with (almost) the same probability, whereas your suggestion decreases the chance of leading 0s. But since a random ulong is almost always longer than 10 digits, it's irrelevant in practice.

Comment: It’s all elementary of course, but instead of add leading zeros result.ToString("D10"), I'd prefer to append a random number to the end of the generated token from RNGCryptoServiceProvider. Yes its predictable but still more random the zeros.

Comment: @Nickz: It adds bias to the randomness, which is never good. Remember - if you have a good RNG, 0000000000 is just as likely as 1572983729.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: I see your point, thanks for your feedback.